# changing checkbox style on uncheck

Tags: javascript, html, css, checkbox

I have a list of checkboxes in a page with all the boxes are checked by default. When user clicks on any particular checkbox to uncheck it, the background color of the checkbox should be changed or the boxes should be checked with cross mark in a red color.

I tried the following on uncheck,

```
document.getElementById("checkBooxId1").style = "background-color:red";
```

This is not working.

Also, I would like to do this on some occasion not all the time. So, when the parent checkbox is checked and the child is unchecked, the style of the unchecked checkebox should be different. Whereas, if the parent is also not checked, then the child and the parent should be in normal style.

Is there any other way?

Comment: Could you paste all the codes?It will help others to find the problem.

Comment: Form elements styling is not so easy, and you need bag of tricks: http://www.inserthtml.com/2012/06/custom-form-radio-checkbox/

Comment: What is a parent checkbox?

Comment: Its a kind of tree structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/2ck4tfj3/1/

```
input[type=checkbox] {
    position: relative;
}
input[type=checkbox].awesome::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: red;
}
```

and just use this to change the background to red dynamically: `document.getElementById("checkbox1").className = "awesome";`

I used CSS pseudo elements to style the input checkboxes when they have the class `awesome`. You can change whether an element has this class with JavaScript.

Comment: Yes, I am able to uncheck or check using this id.

Comment: Even though the code is correct, you can't change the background-color of a checkbox.

Comment: Is there any other way to do some styling on uncheck event?

Comment: You could use CSS psuedo elements like ::after or ::before and style those. Or, you could put a `<div>` after the checkbox and style that.

Comment: I want to do that only when the checkbox is unchecked and it should be reverted to the normal style on checking again.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. But, I would like to do this on some occasion not all the time. So, when the parent checkbox is checked and the child is unchecked, the style of the unchecked checkebox should be different. Whereas, if the parent is also not checked, then the child and the parent should be in normal style.

Comment: I edited my answer again. You can change whether an element's ::after pseudo class is styled or not with classes.

Answer (score 3):

As I said before, you can't change the background-color of a checkbox, but there are workarounds to get the desired effect.

Using JavaScript:

```js
var defaultState = "checked";
var fakecboxes  = document.getElementsByClassName("fakecbox");
for (var i = 0; i < fakecboxes.length; i++) {
 (function (i) {
  if (!fakecboxes[i].classList.contains(defaultState)) {
   fakecboxes[i].classList.add(defaultState);
  }
  fakecboxes[i].onclick = function () {
   if (!this.classList.contains("checked")) {
    this.classList.add("checked");
    this.classList.remove("unchecked");
   } else {
    this.classList.remove("checked");
    this.classList.add("unchecked");
   }
  };
 })(i);
}
```

```css
body {
 user-select: none;
 -webkit-user-select: none;
}
.fakecbox {
 width: 12px;
 height: 12px;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 margin: 3px;
 margin-left: 4px;
 display: inline-block;
 position: relative;
 box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
 background-color: rgb(222, 222, 222);
 background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgb(243, 243, 243) 0%, rgb(224, 224, 224) 40%, rgb(224, 224, 224) 100%);
 border-radius: 2px;
 border-width: 1px;
 border-style: solid;
 border-top-color: rgb(178, 178, 178);
 border-left-color: rgb(167, 167, 167);
 border-right-color: rgb(167, 167, 167);
 border-bottom-color: rgb(167, 167, 167);
}
.fakecbox:hover {
 border-top-color: rgb(168, 168, 168);
 border-left-color: rgb(157, 157, 157);
 border-right-color: rgb(157, 157, 157);
 border-bottom-color: rgb(157, 157, 157);
 box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .125);
 background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgb(244, 244, 244) 0%, rgb(226, 226, 226) 40%, rgb(226, 226, 226) 100%);
}
.fakecbox:active {
 border-top-color: rgb(173, 173, 173);
 border-left-color: rgb(161, 161, 161);
 border-right-color: rgb(161, 161, 161);
 border-bottom-color: rgb(161, 161, 161);
 background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgb(231, 231, 231) 0%, rgb(213, 213, 213) 40%, rgb(213, 213, 213) 100%);
 box-shadow: none;
}
.fakecbox.checked::after {
 content:"";
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 background-image: url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAgAAAAICAMAAADz0U65AAAAM1BMVEX///9CQkJERERMTExPT09WVlZZWVlfX19gYGBlZWVmZmZpaWlra2txcXFycnJzc3N6enq1N2u5AAAAAXRSTlMAQObYZgAAAC5JREFUeAElwYcRACEMwDD7eyHA/tNyuUiUj3JtB+nXBp2pAx5PvYFQd9KrlCAtF1AAoT8ZlaoAAAAASUVORK5CYII=);
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position: center;
}
.fakecbox.red {
 background: rgba(255,0,0,.4);
 border: 1px solid rgba(200,0,0,.5);
}
.fakecbox.redonuncheck.unchecked {
 background: rgba(255,0,0,.4);
 border: 1px solid rgba(200,0,0,.5);
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" />Normal checkbox
<br>
<div class="fakecbox"></div>Fake checkbox
<br>
<div class="fakecbox red"></div>Fake red checkbox
<br>
<div class="fakecbox redonuncheck"></div>Fake red-on-uncheck checkbox
```

---

This one using only CSS. You can remove the last label `<label for="cbox">Normal checkbox</label>`. Checkbox still works. You can modify the `span` for unchecked state and `input:checked + span` for checked state.

```css
.checkbox input {
 display: none;
}
.checkbox span {
 width: 20px;
 height: 20px;
 display: inline-block;
 background-color: red;
}
.checkbox input:checked + span {
 background-color: lime;
}
```

```html
<label class="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox"/>
    <span></span>
</label>
<label for="checkbox">Normal(modified) checkbox</label>
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use CSS psuedo elements.

The :checked pseudo-class in CSS selects elements when they are in the selected state. It is only associated with input () elements of type radio and checkbox . The :checked pseudo-class selector matches radio and checkbox input types when checked or toggled to an on state. If they are not selected or checked, there is no match.

So when a checkbox is checked, and you are targeting the label immediately after it:

CSS:

```
input[type=checkbox] + label {
color: #ccc;
font-style: italic;
} 
input[type=checkbox]:checked + label {
color: #f00;
font-style: normal;
}
```

The label text will turn from grey italic to red normal font.

HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="ossm" name="ossm"> 
<label for="ossm">CSS is Awesome</label>
```

Taken from [CSS-Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/c/checked/)

Hope this helps